# Please why do I get the error "SQLiteException: no such table: tabella (code1)?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Please why do I get the error "SQLiteException: no such table: tabella (code1)???

from LogCat I get: "SQLiteException: no such table: tabella (code1)" when I try to access the database fro the activity.

Here is the SQLiteOpenHelper code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String CREATE_DB_SQL = "CREATE TABLE tabella (_id INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, colonna1 TEXT, colonna2 TEXT, colonna3 TEXT);";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "basedati", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_DB_SQL);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues (3);
        cv.put("colonna1", "valore colonna 1");
        cv.put("colonna2", "valore colonna 3");
        cv.put("colonna3", "valore colonna 3");
        db.insert("tabella", "colonna1", cv);
}

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabella");
        onCreate(db);   
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity code in which I try to open the database:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DatabaseHelper db=null;
    private Cursor constantsCursor=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        constantsCursor=db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT colonna1 FROM  tabella ORDER BY colonna1", null);
        }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the table exists at the time you run the other queries? Your code simply seems to assume that the DB operations succeeded.

Comment: No I am not, that seems to be the point. How do i make sure it exists? By the way: I run only one query (the rawQuery in the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are that you have changed the table after running your app at least once. You cannot simply change the Java String `CREATE_DB_SQL`, you must also update the SQL schema. The easiest way to do this is to increment the version number:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "basedati", null, 2); // Change the number to two 
}
```

Comment: Indeed it solves the issue!!! But now do I make sure it does not happen again every time I run the App as I develop it?

Comment: Just remember: if you change `CREATE_DB_SQL` or anything in `DatabaseHandler#onCreate()`, you must increment this number to execute those changes.